# Cannot Invoke '^' with an argument list of type '($T27, IntegerLiteralConvertible)'

Tags: ios, swift

```
func FindDistance(currentLatitude: Double, currentLongtitude: Double, compareLatitude: Double, compareLongtitdue: Double) -> Double {    
    var dlon = compareLongtitdue - currentLongtitude
    var dlat = compareLatitude - currentLatitude
    let WorldRadius = 6371

    var a = sin(dlat/2)^2 + cos(currentLatitude) * cos(compareLatitude) * sin(dlon/2)^2
    var c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a))
    var d = WorldRadius * c
}
```

`println(FindDistance(11.583431, 104.920141, 11.584966, 104.918569))`

> There is an Error in Line in Variable "a". said 'Cannot Invoke '^' with an argument list of type '($T27, IntegerLiteralConvertible)'.

Comment: Have a look at [CLLocation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/) which has a `distanceFromLocation()` method – no need to implement your own formula ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to use **pow(x,y)** function which returns x raised to the power of y.

So in order to access this function you need to import **Darwin** first and rewrite code as follow:

```
import Darwin

func FindDistance(currentLatitude:Double, currentLongtitude:Double, compareLatitude:Double, compareLongtitdue:Double) -> Double {

        var dlon = compareLongtitdue - currentLongtitude
        var dlat = compareLatitude - currentLatitude
        let WorldRadius: Double = 6371

        var a = pow(sin(dlat/2), 2) + cos(currentLatitude) * cos(compareLatitude)  * pow(sin(dlon/2),2)
        var c = 2 * atan2( sqrt(a), sqrt(1-a) )
        var d = WorldRadius * c

        return d
    }
```

Comment: Actually, I want to convert these JavaScript code to Swift, but i found an error as above. Here is the Origin Source Code. http://andrew.hedges.name/experiments/haversine/